# cant find the right event for a successful upload with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I just included a custom FileManager into CKEditor.
I can see that it is working correctly when using the built in add Image functionality.

**The Problem:** I have is in a Custom "Bootstrap-Carousel" Plugin where I also provided a Image Upload functionality.

**The goal:** Just like the built in add Image thing is activating the next or another tab after a successful upload of an image I want my plugin to do the same. **But it is showing just a red progress bar although image upload was successful on that same tab**. It seems that I am missing some upload success event. But the documentation does not provide information about FileManger events or I could not find any.

Here is my code:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config){
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/admin/upload/';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/admin/upload/';
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/admin/upload/?type=browse';
}
```

The php Router routes requests to `admin/upload` to this php function:

```
public function fileUpload($params){
    $funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'];
    $url = '';
    $error = '';
    if($_FILES['upload']['error'] > 0 ){
        switch($_FILES['upload']['error']){
            case 1: $error = 'upload_max_filesize overflow';
                break;
            case 2: $error = 'max_file_size overflow';
                break;
            case 3: $error = 'File could not upload completely';
                break;
            case 4: $error = 'No File has been uploaded';
                break;
            case 6: $error = 'No temporary Folder given.';
                break;
            case 7: $error = 'Upload aborted: File could not been written.';
                break;
        }
    }
    $allowedTypes = array('text/plain','image/jpeg','image/gif', 'image/png');
    $type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    if(!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)){
        $error = 'This file type is not allowed';
    }
    if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH.'/app/uploads/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'])){
        $error = 'File already exists!';
    }
    if($error === '' && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])){
        $upfile = ROOT_PATH.'/app/uploads/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $upfile)){
            $url = '/app/uploads/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
        }else{
            $error .= 'Could not move File to destination folder!';
        }
    }   
    exit("<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$error');</script>");
}
```

And finally my Plugin upload definition:

```
{
            id: 'tab1',
            label: 'Upload Image',
            title: 'upload',
            elements: [
                    {
                          type: 'file',
                          id: 'upload',
                          label: 'Select file from your computer',
                          size: 38
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'fileButton',
                          id: 'fileId',
                          label: 'Upload file',
                          'for': [ 'tab1', 'upload' ],
                          filebrowser: {
                                action: 'QuickUpload',
                                onSelect: function( fileUrl, error ) {
                                    if(error !== ''){
                                       alert(error);
                                    }
                                   // to cancel built in onSelect
                                   return false;
                                }
                                // now from here - there should be some success event ???
                                // on Success: function(){} ???
                          }
                      }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
onSelect: function( fileUrl, error ) {
            if(error !== ''){
               alert(error);
            }else{
               var document = this.getElement().getDocument();
               var element = document.getById( 'imgPreview' );
               element.setHtml('<img src="'+fileUrl+'" style="width:100px"><br />');
               var dialog = this.getDialog();
               dialog.getContentElement('tab2','id2').focus();
            }
            return false;
       }
```

What I thought is a progress bar was a uncomplete shown xdebug notice error after upload.

Now I upload a picture and then put it into the next tab for further treatment and then get a focus on that tab.